# How to convert Enum to Json object with Header in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, .net, enums

*Here's what I've done so far*

```
public enum TCountryNames
{
  [Display(Name="America")]
  cnUSA = 1,
  [Display(Name="England")]
  cnUK,
  [Display(Name="CHINA")]
  cnCHN
}

public class MyClass
{
  public static List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> GetEnumList()
    {
        var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        foreach (var e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TCountryNames)))
        {
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(e.ToString(), (int)e));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

> Result: [cnUSA,1] with total count 3 and without header

**The result i want is [{"Id":1,"Name":"America"},{"Id":2,"Name":"England"}]**

> I've tried [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
> public TCountryNames Names{ get; set; }

> I've also tried converting enum to array list var names = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TCountryNames));
> ArrayList arrLst = new ArrayList() { names };
> but both of them doesn't seems to be working.

*Any help will be appreciated. Thank You in Advance. *

Comment: Accessing enum attributes; https://stackoverflow.com/a/71247074/4139809

Comment: @jeremyLakeman, it will give me a display name but how do I compose the header as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For get display name value you should use System.Reflection. And then you could do this in simple way:

```
   public enum TCountryNames
    {
        [Display(Name = "America")]
        cnUSA = 1,
        [Display(Name = "England")]
        cnUK,
        [Display(Name = "CHINA")]
        cnCHN
    }

public class EnumData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public static List<EnumData> GetEnumList()
    {
        var list = new List<EnumData>();
        foreach (var e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TCountryNames)))
        {
            list.Add(new EnumData
            { 
                Id = (int)e, 
                Name = e.GetType()
                    .GetMember(e.ToString())
                    .First()?
                    .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?
                    .GetName()
            });
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

So to clarify:

- you create loop foreach enum
- take id by casting
- take name using reflaction - I added all needed protection against null exception

Output:
[
{
"Id": 1,
"Name": "America"
},
{
"Id": 2,
"Name": "England"
},
{
"Id": 3,
"Name": "CHINA"
}
]

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XVL2LI

Answer (score 2):

1. If you don't want to add new class

   ```
    public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetEnumList()
    {
        var list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        foreach (var e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TCountryNames)))
        {
            list.Add(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Id", (int)e }, { "Name", e.ToString() } });
        }
        return list;
    }
   ```
2. Define a model for serialization

   ```
    public class EnumData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public static List<EnumData> GetEnumList()
    {
        var list = new List<EnumData>();
        foreach (var e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TCountryNames)))
        {
            list.Add(new EnumData { Id = (int)e, Name = e.ToString() });
        }
        return list;
    }
   ```